# Как создать jar из maven проекта с установленными флагами

Tags: java, maven, jar

Допустим есть некий проект, для его запуска необходимы флаги мавена. Что-то на подобии -Dкакой-то параметр. Собрав jar, он не работает, так как надо прописывать параметры, как обойти или что можно сделать, чтобы в jar учитывались эти флаги?

Comment: Флаги вида `-Dчто-то` - это флаги не мавена, а JVM. Их нельзя навязать. В некоторых случаях можно в коде использовать значения по умолчанию, если флаг не передан. Какие именно флаги вам нужно передать?

Comment: через -D можно задавать значения property pom файла

Comment: Не совсем понятно что имеется в виде под флагами. Может проще сделать предустановленные конфигурации файлов, а с помощью профилей регулировать что должно попасть в jar ? Вообще можно, передать значения через командную строку, потом их писать одним плагином в файл, другим плагином перемещать, но это все жесть, лучше уж гредл использовать, там с этим все проще.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно добавить в начало `main` метода

```
System.setProperty("name", "value");
```